# Can wordpress shortcodes contain conditional statements?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

Im working with wordpress Advance custom field (acf) plugin.I am trying to make a shortcode which will be use to show latest blog post and i want to retrieve two **acf** field value through if else conditional logic.But i can't use **if else** statement for this shortcode.When im pasting this code into functions.php,my site is showing a blank page with a error message which is showing there unexpected **if** problem.See the problem line.

Code:

```
function latest_shortcode($atts)
{
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'title' => '',
    'category' => ''
), $atts, 'latest' ) );

    $q = new WP_Query(
        array('posts_per_page' => '6', 'post_type' => 'post'));

    // Get the ID of a given category
    $category_id = get_cat_ID( ''.$category.'' );

    // Get the URL of this category
    $category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );

    $list = '<div class="fix single_home_content">
            <div class="fix single_home_content_container">
            <h2><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i> '.$title.' <a href="'.esc_url( $category_link ).'">See all <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a></h2>';

    while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();

        //get the ID of your post in the loop
        $id = get_the_ID();
    $downloadlink = get_field('downloadlink');
        $downloadfile = get_field( "downloadfile" );

        $post_thumbnail=  get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'apps-img' );      
        $list .= '

        <div class="fix single_content floatleft">
        <a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.$post_thumbnail.'</a>
        <h2><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.ShortenText(get_the_title()).'</a></h2>
        <div class="rating">
            '.kk_star_ratings($pid).'
        </div>
        <div class="home_download">
            <a href="'.if($downloadlink){$downloadlink}else{$downloadfile}.'">Download</a>
        </div>
    </div>
        ';        
    endwhile;
    $list.= '</div></div>';
    wp_reset_query();
    return $list;
}

add_shortcode('latest', 'latest_shortcode');
```

I just can't figure it out in this line below from above code.

```
<a href="'.if($downloadlink){$downloadlink}else{$downloadfile}.'">Download</a>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated .

Comment: at the top of your file just after the opening <?php tag.. add.. error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1); .. hopefully you'll see an error rather than a blank white screen! also would be extremely helpful if you indented your example code a bit better...kind of hard to see what's going on in it's present state

Comment: check out my answer below regarding that...but yeah you can't concatenate an if(){} statement in a string, but the ternary form will work if enclosed in ()...

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing this line will cause syntax errors...

```
<a href="'.if($downloadlink){$downloadlink}else{$downloadfile}.'">
```

try changing to...

```
<a href="'.(($downloadlink)?$downloadlink:$downloadfile).'">
```

Also...this line..

```
$category_id = get_cat_ID( ''.$category.'' );
```

should be

```
$category_id = get_cat_ID($category);
```

no need for quotes/concatenation

Comment: I used your above suggestion.But there is nothing in **href** , i mean empty. Thanks for quick response.

Comment: and your sure $downloadlink and $downloadfile are not empty?

Comment: well if $downloadlink is empty it will evaluate to false in the 'if' statement and will use $downloadfile, otherwise it will use $downloadlink ... try changing (($downloadlink)?$downloadlink:$downloadfile) to... 
((!trim($downloadlink))?$downloadfile:$downloadlink)

Comment: a space in $downloadlink (meaning ' ') will still evaluate to true so you need to trim it..

Comment: You are awesome! . Your ternary conditional statement suggestion was perfect.I made a mistake that's why it was not working before.Now it working perfectly.Thank you...